# I am confused about the colon comes after mail_to and subject so someone please explain this

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
mail_to: user.email, subject: "Password Reset"
```

I am new to Rails. I know that colon comes before the symbols, but don't know why it comes after such type of words.

Comment: It has nothin to do with mail_to tag, what you are getting confused here is difference between the symbols and hash syntax introduced with Ruby 1.9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be confusing, especially since :name is valid on its own (as a standalone symbol) but name: has no meaning by itself.

The bottom line is that :name => and name: are effectively the same only inside literal hashes, so that

```
{ :name => "Michael Hartl" }
```

and

```
{ name: "Michael Hartl" }
```

are equivalent, but otherwise you need to use :name (with the colon coming first) to denote a symbol.

This is because both hash syntaxes are still in common use, it’s essential to be able to recognize both of them. (My answer has been referenced from Micheal Hartl's Ruby on Rails)

Answer (score 0):

This syntax was introduced in Ruby 1.9 to make hashes more readable.

```
:subject => "Password Reset"

# Starting from 1.9 you can do
subject: "Password Reset"
```

Both of these syntaxes is a syntax sugar for:

```
{ :subject => "Password Reset" }
```